# Azure EventHub to publish on Topic deployed in PCF space

Tags: pcf, eventhub

Is there any way so that service from Azure EventHub can publish event on Topic which is deployed in PCF cloud?

how the eventhub and pcf integration will happen. is there any cloud function or enpoint is available at azure eventhub to achove the same